# Background image to view which contain a tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have in the Interface builder a view which contain a `UITableView` and a custom `UITableVIewCell`, I would like to add an image view to my view. How I can do this? I have added an image view, but the cell of my table view have a strange color.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make your cells and table view transparent

Answer (score 0):

Add UIImageView to your XIB file and set its IBOutlet.

Now add UITableView to your XIB file on UIImageView and also set its IBOutlet..

Make UITableView's backgroundColor to clearcolor...

Hope this will work...